# Negative depth of actor in clutter toolkit?

Tags: 3d, clutter

I'm programming a simple animated gui using clutter (pyclutter,to be specific, but I don't think that matters) and I need my actors to have a negative depth. The reason for this is that positive depth parameter seems to move them closer to the camera, and this kind of breaks my idea of the layout :-).
I tried playing with `clutter_stage_set_perspective()`, but didn't get anything useful from that.

How can I make the effect of moving my actors behind my "zero" plane instead of forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, so you *can* use negative depth of an actor. Nevermind. The problem was that the actor behind the zero plane was hidden by my
background texture.